# C++ 'overloading' the if() statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, operator-overloading, type-conversion

Is it possible to change the behavior of `if()` so that:

```
class Foo {
    int x;
};

Foo foo;
if(foo)
```

only proceeds if the value of `x` is something other than zero? or...

Would an explicit user-defined type conversion to int work/would that be an appropriate approach? or...

Is it best to do something like `if(foo.getX())`?

Comment: If you need this in a C++03 context, you might want to look into the safe bool idiom: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can convert your object to a boolean value by defining `operator bool()`:

```
explicit operator bool() const 
{ 
    return foo.getX(); 
}
```

The `explicit` keyword prevents implicit conversions from `Foo` to `bool`. For example, if you accidentally put `foo` in an arithmetic expression like `foo + 1`, the compiler could detect this error if you declare `operator bool()` as `explicit`, otherwise `foo` will be converted to `bool` even if not intended.

*In general*, member functions of the form

```
operator TypeName()
```

(with optional `explicit` and `const` qualifier) are conversion operators. It allows you to cast your class to any type specified by `TypeName`. In the other direction, constructors with one argument allow you to cast any type to your class:

```
class Foo {
  Foo(int x);    // convert int to Foo
  operator bool() const;  // convert Foo to bool
  int x;
};
```

This defines implicit conversions for your class. The compiler tries to apply these conversions if possible (like what it does for built-in data types, e.g. `5 + 1.0`). You can declare them to be `explicit` to suppress unwanted implicit conversions.

Comment: Making it explicit is probably better.

Comment: You **definitely** want to mark this explicit unless you want to allow people to do things like `!myClass`.

Answer (score 13):

You can define an operator to convert the object to `bool`

```
class Foo
{
  int x;
public:
  operator bool() const
  {
    return x > 0;
  }
};
```

But this can have unintended consequences because of implicit conversions to `bool` when you don't desire the conversion to take place. For instance

```
int x = 42 + Foo();
```

C++11 solves this problem by allowing you to declare the conversion operator as `explicit`, which then only allows implicit conversions in certain contexts, such as within an `if` statement.

```
explicit operator bool() const // allowed in C++11
```

Now

```
int x = 42 + Foo();  // error, no implicit conversion to bool
int x = 42 + static_cast<bool>(Foo()); // OK, explicit conversion is allowed
```