# How to define new behavior for the if and else statements in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

The project I am working on involves a class, let it be *myClass*, which is similar to a set, and I need to allow the programmer to compare objects of this type in a meaningful way.

What I would like to be able to do is something like this:

```
myClass a, b;
...
if (a == b)
{
    //execute code where a and b are implicitly used as
    // each of a and b's elements, respectively
}
```

and have my custom if statement execute the conditional code for each pair of elements from a and b, based on the condition performed on the pair of elements.

Here is a more concrete example:

```
myClass a = {1, 2}, b = {2, 3};

if (a == b)
    std::cout << a << " equals " << b << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << a << " does not equal " << b << std::endl;
```

Where the result would be (not necessarily in this order):

```
1 does not equal 2
2 equals 2
1 does not equal 3
2 does not equal 3
```

Currently, I have comparison operators overloaded to return a "comparison type" which simply stores the two operands and the comparison function for lazy evaluation. Is there a way to accomplish this custom if/else behavior so that it occurs whenever an if statement receives a parameter of type "comparison type?" Or is it necessary to just define a regular function which accepts an object of this type and a reference to a binary operator function as the conditional code?

I saw this question, but simply defining a conversion to bool will not work in this case.
[C++ 'overloading' the if() statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431895/c-overloading-the-if-statement)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575766/comparison-operator-overloading  Overload the == operator and then use boolean if/else logic

Comment: Just read it again. No, you can't do this. You probably can achieve something similar with [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) and [boost::zip_iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html), but, I mean, it's much easier (and clearer) to just write two nested `for`'s and iterate by hand.

Comment: "*simply defining a conversion to bool will not work in this case*" - why not? That is exactly what an `if` statement expects. If you overload `operator==` to return a "comparison type" rather than `bool`, that type MUST be convertible to `bool`. See [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/). Internally, you can compare elements however you want, as long as the final result can be represented as a `bool`. If you are using C++20, have a look at the new `operator<=>` instead, which is more flexible.

Comment: No, you can't change the meaning of `if` and `else` to execute the controlled statements more times. You could get something similar with a different syntax, maybe something like `each_elem_if_else(a == b, [](const auto& x, const auto& y) { std::cout << x << " equals " << y << std::endl; }, [](const auto& x, const auto& y) { std::cout << x << " does not equal " << y << std::endl; });`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Note the desired result involves executing the if-statement once and the else-statement three times.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "To compare objects of this type in a meaningful way." Because reducing the *compound comparison* to a single bool would invalidate the comparison. Thanks for sharing `operator<=>`.

Comment: @aschepler That is what I had in mind as a backup, but would prefer to reuse the if-else syntax because it would better reflect the operation. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @CássioRenan Thanks for the links. I agree that nested `for` loops are the best option either way, I just think it would be more concise and elegant to do all that under-the-hood.

Comment: If by "concise and elegant" you mean "cryptic and confusing' then I agree. Least surprise principle!

Comment: @n.m. That is true. Although I must add that it would be difficult to be surprised by an explicitly invoked feature...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this close:

```
myClass a = {1, 2}, b = {2, 3};

for(auto&& cmp:(a == b))
  if(cmp)
    std::cout << cmp.lhs << " equals " << cmp.rhs << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << cmp.lhs << " does not equal " << cmp.rhs << std::endl;
```

simply define `operator==` on two `myClass` to return an iterable.

Each iterable element has a `lhs`, a `rhs` and a conversion to `bool` operator.

```
template<class Lhs, class Rhs=Lhs, class Cmp=std::equal<>>
struct comparison_t {
  Lhs lhs;
  Rhs rhs;
  operator bool()const{ return Cmp{}(lhs, rhs); }
};

struct myClass {
  int a, b;
  auto operator==( myClass const& lhs, myClass const& rhs ){
    std::array<comparison_t<int const&>> retval={{
      {lhs.a, rhs.a},
      {lhs.b, rhs.a},
      {lhs.a, rhs.b},
      {lhs.b, rhs.b},
    }};
    return retval;
  }
};
```

there are probably some typos.

Comment: That is very clever, thanks a lot. The only issue I can see with it, though, is that for `myClass` operands with a large number of elements, expanding the comparison into a `std::array` will require a substantial amount of memory. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: @wwill yes; look up what `for(:)` loops do.  You just have to calculate what `*` should return and what `++` should do and how to handle end and `!=`.  The array solution is just the easiest one.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away from the `if`/`else` style, you can get the bodies of the `if` and `else` blocks as lambda to a helper function.

```
template<class T, class F> void compare_all(const myClass &a, const myClass &b, T fn_true, F fn_false) {
    for (const auto &ai: a.vec) {
        for (const auto &bi: b.vec) {
            if (ai == bi)
                fn_true(ai, bi);
            else
                fn_false(ai, bi);
        }
    }
}
```

The first two parameters to `compare_all` are the same as you'd have for `operator==`.  The other two are the lambdas to hold the actions to do when the elements compare equal or not.  The example here assumes there is a container named `vec` in the `myClass` class that holds the items to compare.

As an example for how it is used, here is how your original code can be rewritten to use this technique.

```
int main() {
    myClass a{1, 2}, b{2, 3};

    compare_all(a, b, 
        [](int a, int b) { std::cout << a << " equals " << b << std::endl; },
        [](int a, int b) { std::cout << a << " does not equal " << b << std::endl; }
    );
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I had in mind in case the native if/else style couldn't be used. This answer could be tailored to the given problem by adding a `bool(condition)(const myClass& a, const myClass& b)` parameter to `compare_all` in lieu of the hard-coded `operator==`, as well as by making `fn_false` optional. Thank you.